# React this.setState not updating array state variable

Tags: arrays, reactjs

There are many postings about react state update involving array, but none of them seem to address my case.

I'm using the FullCalendar.io component which accepts an array of events as a prop from the parent component, and populates the calendar cells. I tried to setState 'cal_events_state' based on nextProps.cal_events, but for some reason cal_event_state is set to [] (apparently the initial state value is overwritten).

What am I missing?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var $ = require ('jquery')

var Calendar = React.createClass ({
  render: function() {
    return <div id="calendar"></div>;
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        cal_events_state: [{"due": "201505", "title": "Production"}]
        , test_state: 11
      }
  },

componentDidMount: function() {
var self = this;
const var_cal_events = this.props.cal_events; //This prop is blank at this point because ajax hasn't returned an array yet.
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: var_cal_events;
    })
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    var self = this;
    var var_cal_events = nextProps.cal_events;  // after receiving the ajax fetch payload, this has some event tasks.

    this.setState({
      cal_events_state: var_cal_events, // This doesn't update state with the newly received payload
      test_state: 22            // This updates state
})
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: var_cal_events

})

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

},


});
```

Comment: why are you creating the calendar twice? and why are you using es5 and es6 intermingled? And on top of that, you should probably not use jquery here. there are other ways to have a calendar and that way you dont have a ton of dom manipulation outside of react (which is the preferred practice)

Comment: Do you have a link to a better react calendar example?

Comment: I mean just do a simple google search.. found results like this. [Link1](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker).... [Link2](https://github.com/zippyui/react-date-picker)....  [Bunch of different examples](https://react.rocks/tag/DatePicker)...

Comment: Thanks. I like react-big-calendar.

Comment: You're welcome.. remember Google is your friend. If you want a react calendar just search for "react calendar" and been you have it :) when you are stuck just try googling the exact issue and you should be able to find the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out that 'setState' does update the state variable, but I didn't realize it doesn't do so until the execution of the function is completed (ie. until your code exit the function block. I was checking the this.state.variable right after the setState statement, which made it look like the variable is not updated.

Comment: this was stressing me out so much so thanks for this!

Comment: Thank you for you answer. my array didn't update at one click when i used setState. whereas when i push to a const MyArray = [] it updated quickly. :)

Comment: I spent more than 2 hours trying to debug what looked like a statue update issue :| And then came across your answer. This is a lifesaver, thank you!