# Can't properly update React state variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am working om my first React app (dice roll app). I am having troble when I call function to rol the dice, so randomly give my necesary random number for each dice.

Here is my constructor inside App class and two function I want to be executed when button is pressed. When I press the button function `rollTheDice()` is executed and giver random numbers and also (kind of) updates state with `this.setState({diceNumber: copyDiceNumber});` and then when function `diceSum()` is run it sums up old state dates. For example in first "dice roll" function `sum()` will give number 2.

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            diceNumber: [1,1],
            total: 0,
        }
    }

    rollTheDice = () => {
        // console.log(this.state.diceNumber);

        console.log("Before roling" + this.state.diceNumber)

        let copyDiceNumber = this.state.diceNumber.slice();

        copyDiceNumber.map( (e,i) => {

            // console.log(e);

            copyDiceNumber[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1)
        });

        this.setState({diceNumber: copyDiceNumber});

        this.diceSum();

        console.log("After roling" + this.state.diceNumber)

        // console.log(this.state.diceNumber);

    };

    diceSum = () => {
        let sum = 0;

        for (let i of this.state.diceNumber){
            sum = sum + i;
            console.log(sum);
        }
        this.setState({total: sum})
    };
```

I red that it could be because on how React renders state, in article [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533692/react-this-setstate-not-updating-array-state-variable) it says that state is updated after function is completed, but how I can call `diceSum()` function only after `rollTheDice()` function is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` takes a second argument, a function, which is called only after the state has been set. So you can use the same here like this

```
   ... 
   this.setState({diceNumber: copyDiceNumber}, this.diceSum);
   ...

   or

   ... 
   this.setState({diceNumber: copyDiceNumber}, () => this.diceSum());
   ...
```

Comment: When I try to do this ` this.setState({diceNumber: copyDiceNumber}, this.diceSum());`, then I put `console.log("After roling" + this.state.diceNumber)` in `diceSum()` and I get printed values 1,1. That means that state does not updates until function is not compleated.

Comment: @Austris Notice that there are no brackets in my answer. You are doing `this.diceSum()` instead of `this.diceSum`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake your code is correct, I have just added `this.diceSum()` with parenthesis.